# Why doesn't Karabiner map F2 from the touch bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, touch-bar, karabiner

I used Karabiner to map `f2` to `return_or_enter`, so that F2 can rename files in the Finder. The configuration is "for all devices", not specific keyboards and is taken directly from Karabiner on-line configuration options "Use F2 as Rename."

This works on my external  keyboards (Apple and Microsoft), but not in the touch bar.

Apparently touch bar F2 is not being detected as such--even though Karabiner EventViewer shows its events as code 59, f2, just like the external keyboard.

Touch bar configuration is shown below.

How can I configure this correctly in Karabiner?

[image: f-key settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's your setting problem.
https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1700

Comment: Thank you-- different question, but same answer. The solution is to enable, in Karabiner Devices Tab, the "No Product Name (No Manufacturer name), Vendor ID 1452, Product ID 34304.